# web scrapping ¿ como buscar lista de precios en código de pagina?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

¿Cómo buscar lista de precios en código de página?

Este es el código que estoy probando, si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecería:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
# URL de la página del producto que deseas analizar
url_producto = 'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/notebooks'
    
# Realiza una solicitud GET para obtener el contenido de la página
response = requests.get(url_producto)
    
# Verifica si la solicitud fue exitosa (código de estado 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Utiliza BeautifulSoup para encontrar la lista de precios
    # Asumiendo que los precios están dentro de una lista HTML <ul> o <ol>
    precios_lista = soup.find('ul', class_='nombre-clase-de-la-lista-de-precios') or \
                   soup.find('ol', class_='nombre-clase-de-la-lista-de-precios')
    
    if precios_lista:
        # Extrae los elementos de la lista de precios
        precios = [precio.text.strip() for precio in precios_lista.find_all('li')]
    
        # Imprime la lista de precios
        for precio in precios:
            print("Precio:", precio)
```

Comment: y como se llama la clase que estas buscando???

Comment: Como hago para buscar la lista de precios  dentro del codigo? no se que poner en xpath.

Comment: eso es lo que tenes que analizar vos en la pagina donde estas buscando ;)

Comment: Lo que necesito es saber como hago para buscar las clases y listas de precios dentro del codigo.

Comment: Tenes que analizar el html de la pagina que queres scrapear para buscar donde estan los valores que queres obtener... no se que esperas como respuesta.. sabes eso ya? lo buscaste?

Comment: Si te molesta , no tenes la obligación de responder. En todo caso, si sabes mas que otros, podes enseñar y no responder de la forma despectiva.

Comment: Hola. Tu código no parece Java. ¿Por qué pusiste la etiqueta `java` en la pregunta?

Comment: En el mejor de los casos, puedes evitar leer la estructura HTML extrayendo la información de `document.body.textContent`

Comment: podes abrir la página en un navegador reciente, boton derecho sobre el precio opción inspeccionar y en el developer tools que se abre por lo general te muestra un xpath tentativo debajo del inspector html ( sobre la consola si es vista integrada ). tené en cuenta que la página que estas intentando escrapear posee un api para esas consultas y que en esos casos por lo general se implementan tecnicas q dificultan el escrapeado normal ( clases dinámicas, honeypots, etc )

Comment: Rockhola, @gbianchi te está dando su tiempo para guiarte, te está enseñando a pensar (te está dando información que **no** has especificado en la pregunta y eso es un avance aunque no lo veas así). Aprende a reconocer eso, nadie está en el sitio en mal plan. Aquí unas recomendaciones generales de cómo construir preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 una pregunta bien estructurada es una pregunta a medio resolver. Saludos.

Comment: Que bueno bueno Mateo. Muchas gracias. Me ayudaste un montón.

Comment: Muchas gracias Malberez. Dos genios.

Comment: Lo comentarios negativos que se ayudan de forma corporativa no me interesan.

Comment: Normal, no pasa nada, todos tienen intereses diferentes, prioridades diferentes, vidas diferentes, también perspectivas de ayuda diferentes y ya, la vida sigue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería utilizar la API de Mercado Libre.

Al optar por hacer scrapping en la página, existe el detalle de encontrar el elemento correcto que corresponda a lo que se necesita.
Al utilizar la API, se obtendrá un resultado más directo y rápido, y las posibilidades de que ocurran errores serán mínimas:

Aquí tienes una buena [API como referencia](https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?q=notebooks)

Codificar en Python utilizaría menos recursos que hacer scrapping.

En esta propuesta se utilizará json y requests y se usará un bucle en la lista de resultados.

```
import json
import requests

item="notebooks"

api = f'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?q={item}'
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'}

response = requests.get(api, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
  dic = response.json()
  for elem in dic['results']:
      print(f"{elem['title']}: R$: {elem['price']}\n")
else:
  print(response.status_code)
```

Las bibliotecas json y requests, requests se utilizan para hacer las solicitudes HTTP y json para decodificar las respuestas JSON de la API de Mercado Libre.

No se incluyó la cantidad de artículos ni el país, estos detalles pueden ser agregados en la investigación.

Resultado de los precios

```
print(f"R$: {elem['price']}")
```

..

```
R$: 2399
R$: 999
R$: 4099
R$: 3499
R$: 2024.4
```

Comment: Es un trabajo de la facultad....

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos . Me ayudaron un monto n voy entendiendo un poco mas gracias a ustedes.